# Shell script with password that starts with (

Tags: shell-script, quoting, ftp

I have a shell script that opens ftp, then passes on the user ID and password.   The password starts with `(` and the server does not like it. It errors outs with a failure to log in message. How can I get past this, without having to change the password? I tried single quotes and that failed also.

Comment: Unclear: Does not show what they are doing. Does not mention what FTP client is used on what Unix.

Comment: pastebin a copy of the script minus your user/server/ip information. Please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.netrc` file (located in your home directory). At least most of ftp clients can use the information in this file for authentication purpose. The format is:

```
machine example.com
login <username>
password <password>
```

You should replace `<username>` with your username and `<password>` with your password.

The only disadvantage is the username and the password will be visible to anyone who can read the file.